# aerospike data not found on after server restart

Tags: aerospike

I am new to `aerospike DB`. I inserted data from `mysql` to `aerospike` using a migration script. Due to some issue `aerospike` server was restarted.
But after the restart, there was no data in `aerospike DB`.

Can someone please let me know what could be the issue? Any config problem in `Aerospike` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the storage mechanism that you used with Aerospike? Did you use one of the default databases? One of the defaults is a in-memory only. Hence, data will be lost if it is an in-memory storage only with a single node and is restarted.

So basically you should ensure that the database storage is configured for persistence[1], has replication factor 2 or more and the suggested minimum number of servers in the cluster should be atleast equal to replication factor to ensure HA.

[1]https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/storage/#recipe-for-an-ssd-storage-engine

Comment: Thanks Anshu ! i checked the configuration in `aerospike.conf` and it was set to `storage-engine memory`